# LOAD CSV command keeps using old file: location, ignores command input

Tags: csv, neo4j, load

I am using Community edition 3.0.5 on Windows 10 . I made multiple efforts to execute a LOAD CSV command before being told that such files cannot reside on an external drive. When I moved the file to users/user/ and tried to execute the LOAD CSV command I got the same message "Couldn't load the external resource at: file:/F:/Neo4j%20DBs/Data.gov%20Consumer%20Complaints/Consumer%20Complaints%20DB/import/Users/CharlieOh/Consumer_Complaints.csv" in spite of the fact the command I entered was 
"LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM
'file:///Users/CharlieOh/Consumer_Complaints.csv' AS line
WITH line
LIMIT 1
RETURN line" 
I tried to locate the file neo4j.conf and could only find C:\Program Files (x86)\Neo4j Community 3.2.2\Neo4j Community.install4j\i4jparams.conf . I even deleted the old DB and recreated the small amount of data and got the same error, which seems to indicate that the LOAD CSV function is totally useless across all my neo4j databases. BTW the %20 in the file specification was due to suggestions on Stack Overflow as well as using underscores to avoid any use of blank spaces in the file specification. None of it worked and now that I believe that I may have solved the problem by putting the csv file in the user directory, the LOAD CSV function won't let me do it. One last thing, I am following the YouTube video   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eh_79goBRUk to learn how to load a csv file into neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

The csv file needs to go in the import directory of the specific database. With Neo4j Desktop this is easy to identify by clicking on the Manage button of the database and then the open folder button. It looks like you've found it.

Once the database import directory is located, you specify it in the LOAD CSV with the statement `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///" + FN + "'`where FN is your file name, including the csv extension. You do **NOT** use the full path; that is assumed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to stumble into that knowledge and should have replied earlier. I am really just beginning to get into the nitty-gritty of graph DBs, neo4j in particular. I have successfully used the above knowledge to load a few databases into neo4j and am now moving into the data analytics stage where I can put the graph structured data to some real use. Thanks for the assist!